# Something crazy happens with StringBuilder.append(String str);

Tags: java

I've got a problem with my java-project.

following function should deliver a String for a SQL-Statement:

```
private static String createInsertString(Pat p)
{   
    StringBuilder x = new StringBuilder();


    x.append(""  + p.getPatnr() +","+ p.getSvnr());

    java.sql.Date andat = null,gebdat;

    if(p.getAndat()==null)
        andat=null;
    else
        andat=new java.sql.Date(p.getAndat().getTimeInMillis());

    if(p.getGebdat()==null)
        gebdat=null;
    else
        gebdat=new java.sql.Date(p.getGebdat().getTimeInMillis());

    x.append("," + andat==null?"null":andat);
    x.append("," + p.getTele()==null?"null":p.getTele());
    x.append("," + p.getVName() +","+ p.getNname());
    x.append("," + p.getKk()==null?"null":p.getKk());
    x.append("," + gebdat==null?"null":gebdat);
    x.append("," + p.getAdrplzort()==null?"null":6);
    x.append("," + p.getAdrstr()==null?"null":p.getAdrstr());
    x.append("," + p.getAdrhnr()==null?"null":p.getAdrhnr());
    s.append("," + p.getReplzort()==null?"null":p.getReplzort().getPlzortnr());
    x.append("," + p.getRestr()==null?"null":p.getRestr());
    x.append("," + p.getRehnr()==null?"null":p.getRehnr());
    x.append("," + p.getLevel());
    x.append("," + p.getCon()==null?"null":p.getCon());
    x.append("," + (p.isPa()?"y":"n")+","+ (p.isLonly()?"y":"n") +","+ (p.isGest()?"y":"n"));
    x.append("," + p.getBem()==null?"null":p.getBem());
    x.append("," + (p.isKat1()?'y':'n') +","+ (p.isKat2()?'y':'n') +","+ (p.isKat3()?'y':'n'));

    System.out.println(x);

    return x.toString();
}
```

the output is

```
6,6465136nullnull,Jürgen,Wieslernullnull6nullnullnullnull,0null,n,n,nnull,n,n,n
```

but it should be like this:

```
6,6465136,null,null,Jürgen,Wiesler,null,null,6,null,null,null,null,0,null,n,n,n,null,n,n,n
```

Anyone an Idea?
I'm using jdk 1.7 on debian(64-bit)

Comment: Couple people already found the problem and gave you the answer below, but I have a random question. What is `java.sql.Date andat = null,gebdat;` ???  Is that some new way to initialize Objects I haven't seen yet, am I just totally blanking and will feel really dumb when I see the answer, or what lol?

Comment: BTW you append to "s" once, is that a typo?

Comment: By the looks of it, you might want to consider using `java.sql.PreparedStatement`. Using dynamic SQL is inviting injection vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 11):

The problem is how the operators bind. Look at this:

```
x.append("," + andat==null?"null":andat);
```

Now think of it as:

```
x.append(("," + andat) == null ? "null" : andat);
```

The LHS is *never* going to be null, so it's always just appending `andat`... and that *still* converts to "null" if the reference is null, because that's the default behaviour of `StringBuilder`.

Your code is *much* more complicated - and inefficient - than it needs to be. Consider rewriting it as:

```
private static String createInsertString(Pat p)
{   
    StringBuilder x = new StringBuilder();
    java.sql.Date andat = p.andat == null ? null 
        : new java.sql.Date(p.getAndat().getTimeInMillis());
    java.sql.Date gebdat = p.getGebdat() == null ? null 
        : new java.sql.Date(p.getGebdat().getTimeInMillis());

    x.append(p.getPatnr()).append(",")
     .append(p.getSvnr()).append(",")
     .append(andat).append(",")
     .append(p.getTele()).append(",")

     // etc

    return x.toString();
}
```

Note that I think you had a bug in the original:

```
x.append("," + p.getVName() +","+ p.getNname());
```

Where these *meant* to be calling two different getters?

Comment: +1: The check is redundant way as `x.append("," + (andat==null?"null":andat));` is the same as `x.append("," + andat);`

Comment: This doesn't even need the StringBuilder.  Simple string concat would work fine as well.

Comment: @Robin: Yes, it would - if it could all be done in a single expression. It's possible that it could at the moment, although it would be a pretty enormous expression. It will be easier to add extra logic later this way though.

Answer (score 4):

You are misusing `.append()` by putting concatenations inside them! This misses the entire point of what `StringBuilder` is supposed to be used for.

```
 x.append("," + andat==null?"null":andat);
```

should be

```
 x.append(",").append( andat == null ? "null" : andat);
```

which would be the correct logic to make your ternary operator work as you intended.

`.append()` returns a reference to the `StringBuilder` so that you can chain `.append()` calls as much as you need.

Anytime you are putting a string concatenation inside of `.append()` you are just creating more intermediate `String` objects that eat up memory, cpu cycles and then use more resources as they now need to be garbage collected.

Also you should pre-allocate your `StringBuilder` with a default size that is slightly bigger than what you expect your contents to be to avoid wasted allocations and garbage creation.

See the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#StringBuilder%28int%29) for the `StringBuilder(int)` constructor.

Answer (score 3):

The problem comes from your '+'.

1. If you use a StringBuilder, don't use '+': it is not efficient
2. `"," + andat==null?"null":andat` results in `",null"==null?"null":andat` if andat is null.

The '+' string concatenation has priority over the ternary operator

When you use the '+' with String your compiler actually translates that to a StringBuilder (or a StringBuffer before Java5)

So having

```
String s = a + b + c;
```

is actually translated to:

```
String s = new StringBuilder().append(a).append(b).append(c).toString().
```

Therefore using + within a StringBuilder is counter-productive as you create additional unecessary StringBuilder.